# How to exclude request for static content from Filter

Tags: java, tomcat, filter

I have an app written in java7 and working on tomcat 7 where have a filter. this is my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>image</filter-name>
    <filter-class>us.sourcio.monitorus.filter.UserAccessFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>excludedURLs</param-name>
        <param-value>MonitisUptimeSnapshot.gadget;</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>image</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but the problem is that this filter handles all request for static contents html, img etc. How to solve this problem any idea ?

Comment: D you want to filter only images?

Comment: no, I want to make the system avoid the filter every time when there is a call to load any static content, not only img. but also html , css atc

Comment: Presumably you have a Servlet with defined mapping, so make the filter use the same mapping, which is best done by replacing the `<url-pattern>` element inside the `<filter-mapping>` with a `<servlet-name>` element.

Comment: Do you mean to make filter to work only when there is call for any of my servlets only, so something like this 
<servlet-name>Srvlet 1</servlet-name>
<servlet-name>Srvlet 2</servlet-name>
<servlet-name>Srvlet 3</servlet-name>

Comment: Can you share the code for **UserAccessFilter.java** ?

Comment: unfortunately no (